# Avoiding multiple nested loops

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

How can I achieve the below **without nested** for loops:

`invitations` is an array with the following structure:

**INVITATIONS**:

```
[{
    "id": "TDK4QP788FOLMHQSZAFSYVVQ182RGM83",
    "date_created": "2016-11-08T15:37:04.409Z",
    "events": [{
        "end_time": "21:00",
        "start_time": "20:00"
    }]
}, {
    "id": "DEI4644LAR91SKGUKMR7RTWY3CMC7PCP",
    "date_created": "2016-11-08T03:57:11.145Z",
    "events": [{
        "end_time": "23:45",
        "start_time": "06:00"
    }]
}]
```

**EVENTS:**

```
[{
    "end_time": "23:45",
    "start_time": "06:00"
}, {
    "end_time": "23:45",
    "start_time": "06:00"
}, {
    "end_time": "23:45",
    "start_time": "06:00"
}, ]
```

I was thinking to loop over the invitations array, then loop through every events item and then compare that item start and end times to each item in the events array while also looping over the events array.

I think i might be over doing this. Is there another possible way to do this without three or more nested loops?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think part of question is missing... what do you mean by "achieve the below" ?? What is the "below" I only see the starting structures?

Comment: I think the below is `events`.

Comment: Question is extremely unclear, what do you mean by "achieve by below", the below seems to have no clear relation

Comment: I need to compare the dates as explained. I don't want to iterate however multiple times. Starting with each event under invitations to be compared with the other array of events.

Comment: Oh :) so then @valentin answer below will extract the events from invitations and just for..for on the two event lists to compair

Comment: Don't forget to mark as rightful answer ;)

Answer (score 4):

Using mapping its very easy. See [lodash `_.map`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.6#map).

```js
var results = _.map(invitations, 'events');
```

Can be also achieved in ES6 with

```js
 var results = invitations.map(function(invitation) {
     return invitation.events;
 });
```

But lodash implementation is faster.

Comment: No idea. I wondered too. There is a war raging between `underscore` and `lodash` users, might have something to do with that. Because there is no way to be cleaner than this.

Comment: actually, there is. with lodash you can just write
`var results = _.map(invitations, 'events');`

Comment: FWIW you can do that with underscore too.

Comment: Yeah, this would make sense. They are almost clones.

Comment: So i'd map events and then have just one nested for loop correct?

Comment: @ValentinRoudge what's lodash doing to map events?

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? Not sure I got it right

Comment: You want to make sure the two arrays are similar, right?

Comment: I want to check for conflicts later by comparing the times... But i was asking what is lodash doing internally..

Comment: Basically the same thing than Object.map. Except that it is faster. I don't really know the details of the implementation though. You should look into lodash source code.

Answer (score -1):

**Try this i hope it will work :**

Here, we have to iterate the `invitations` array two times to get the events array elements and created a new array as per the requirement.

**Working demo :**

```js
var invitations = [{
    "id": "TDK4QP788FOLMHQSZAFSYVVQ182RGM83",
    "date_created": "2016-11-08T15:37:04.409Z",
    "events": [{
        "end_time": "21:00",
        "start_time": "20:00"
    }]
}, {
    "id": "DEI4644LAR91SKGUKMR7RTWY3CMC7PCP",
    "date_created": "2016-11-08T03:57:11.145Z",
    "events": [{
        "end_time": "23:45",
        "start_time": "06:00"
    }]
}];

var events = [];

for (var i in invitations) {
  for (var j in invitations[i].events) {
    events.push(invitations[i].events[j]); 
  }
}
 
document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(events);
```

```css
#results {
  font-weight : bold;
  }
```

```html
<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: While this works, he did ask for solutions *without* nested for loops.